# UDP multicast filename to peers and send/receive found file in peer using TCP

Tags: java, sockets, p2p, file-sharing

I am doing an college assignment on p2p. What I need to accomplish is to create and join **multicast group** and send filename request using UDP from **peer1 to other peers and lookup file in other peers and send/receive the file from peer (say peer2)** to peer1 using TCP and make each peer client/server I tried with following code but it says address already in use and IO exception, please help me

**Main method Peer**

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Peer {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        // we need to give following argument
        //1. destination multicast group and port (e.g. 228.5.6.7 8888)
        //2. the peer's ID (e.g. PPP1)
        MulticastSocket ms = null;
        try {
            //joining the multicastgroup
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            String peerId = new String(args[2]);
            ms =  new MulticastSocket(port);
            ms.joinGroup(group);

            //now utilizing multitheread services for receive and send
            new PeerService2(ms, peerId);
            new PeerService1(ms, group, port, peerId);
        } catch (SocketException e){System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());}
    }

}
```

**class to send udp request and download the file**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.rmi.CORBA.Util;



public class PeerService1 extends Thread {

    MulticastSocket ms = null;
    InetAddress group = null;
    int port = 8888;
    String peerId;
    public BufferedReader stdin;

    public PeerService1(MulticastSocket ms, InetAddress group, int port, String peerId) {
        this.ms = ms;
        this.group = group;
        this.port = port;
        this.peerId = peerId; 

        this.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
         String filename = null;
         stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         while (true) {  
             System.err.print("Enter the File Name:");
             try {
                 filename = stdin.readLine();
                 filename = new String(filename);
             byte [] f = filename.getBytes();
             DatagramPacket messageOut = new DatagramPacket(f, f.length, group, port);
             ms.send(messageOut);
             download(group, port, filename);

             } catch (SocketException ex) {System.out.println("Socket:" + ex.getMessage());
             }
             catch (IOException ex) {
                 System.out.println("IO:" + ex.getMessage());
             }    
        }
    }  
    public void download (InetAddress group, int port, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(""+group+"", port);
        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dOut.writeUTF(filename);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(in);

        String dwnfile = filename + "-download";

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dwnfile);
        System.out.println("The file of" + filename + "was found. Downloaded and saved as" + dwnfile);
        dOut.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();



    }
}
```

**class to handle receive udp request and send file**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class PeerService2 extends Thread {

    MulticastSocket ms = null;
    String peerId;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket = null;

    public PeerService2(MulticastSocket ms, String peerId) {
        this.ms = ms;
        this.peerId = peerId;

        this.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {

         while (true)
        {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                //receive the multicast messages
                byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
                DatagramPacket messageIn = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                ms.receive(messageIn);
                String filename =  new String(messageIn.getData(),0,messageIn.getLength());
                String fileToSend = filename + ".txt";
                System.out.println(fileToSend);
                serverSocket =  new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                File peerFile = new File(fileToSend);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) peerFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(peerFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            //handle file send over socket
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

            //Sending file name and file size to the server
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(peerFile.getName());
            dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println("File "+peerFile+" sent to client.");


                }
             catch (SocketException e) { System.out.println("Socket:" + e.getMessage());
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){ System.out.println("Socket:" + e.getMessage());
            }catch (EOFException e){System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage());
            }catch (IOException e){System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
            } 

        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case If you still didn't found any solution. 
You wanna create a ServerSocket after requesting file from peers. and peer will fetch the socket address from datagram packet to connect to the server socket if file has been found by any peer.

Pseudo code:

PeerService1:
 1. Multicast message to request file
 2. After requesting create ServerSocket and wait for any client to connect back to send file.  (Don't forget to add timeout on server socket, if no client returned with file found).

PeerService2:
 1. Receive the Multicast packet and fetch the file name.
 2. do a lookup for file in filesystem.
 3. if file found then fetch the requesting peer socket address from datagram packet and connect back to send file. You should create a Socket here.

TIP:- Don't forget to close streams and sockets. you don't want peers to wait on sockets.
There may be  few mistakes in what I have written. I'm in hurry. :/
Comment if anything is not clear. I'll post the code example if needed.

Comment: You need to create the server socket *first*. Otherwise you can't be sure you will get that port when sending out the datagrams.

Comment: Seriously? Can't you put your brain to use a predefined port which can be different than the one is being accepted from command-line. I don't think there is any such hard and fast rule in such small programming assignment that you can't use another port.. :D Have you even read the program?